# Swift TRON Content Type HeaderBuilder Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, swift, api, alamofire

I'm using TRON to access an api based with ruby on rails, I sense that my problem is because the header does not have the correct information. I've been playing with the HeaderBuilder syntax from TRON but not able to really see what the syntax needs to be. My rails error is when trying to get data from a specific controller action

```
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with 
Hash (0.25ms)
Filter chain halted as :ensure_valid_accept_media_type rendered or 
redirected
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 61ms (Views: 30.0ms | ActiveRecord: 
 2.7ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

In xcode, I am using a rest type controller for getting json

```
public class DataController {
static let tron = TRON(baseURL: GlobalVariables().baseURL)

class Fetched: JSONDecodable {
    let response: JSON
    required init(json: JSON) throws {
        let response = json
        self.response = response
    }
}

class FetchFailed: JSONDecodable {
    let response: JSON
    required init(json: JSON) throws {
        let response = json
        self.response = response
    }
}

func FetchData(url_param: String) {
    let FetchRequest: APIRequest<Fetched, FetchFailed> = DataController.tron.request(url_param)
    FetchRequest.perform(withSuccess: { (Fetched) in
        print("Success", Fetched)
    }) { (err) in
        print("Error")
    }
}

func Get(parameters: [String:Any], path: String) -> APIRequest<Fetched, FetchFailed> {
    let request: APIRequest<Fetched, FetchFailed> = DataController.tron.request(path)
    request.parameters = parameters

    request.headerBuilder.headers(forAuthorizationRequirement: AuthorizationRequirement.allowed, including: ["Accept":"application/vnd.api+json"])
    return request
}
```

I have added the headerbuilder call in the method, but I think I also need content type. I've spent a day on this already, needing to figure it out to not miss deadlines :( thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I fixed that issue by adding `request.headers = ["Accept":"application/vnd.api+json"]` to my `Get` function instead of `request.headerBuilder....` now though I'm getting my 200 code response but for some reason my `APIRequest<Fetched, FetchFailed>` call is getting `FetchFailed` even though the json response is not erroring at all