# TRON not using request.header

Tags: httprequest, xcode8, alamofire

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

I am using TRON (which includes Alamofire) to make HTTP Request to my REST API.
I have been successful getting a simple API working with this setup.  I am trying to connect to a different API, which requires me to set the headers.  It is this API that is throwing a Status 415 server error.

I have the following code to make the request via TRON.  According to the [TRON Github page](https://github.com/MLSDev/TRON), I should be ae to set the header like this:

```
request.headers = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]
```

I have also tried:

```
request.headerBuilder.headers(forAuthorizationRequirement: AuthorizationRequirement.allowed, including: ["Content-Type":"application/json"])
```

I tried adding a few different ways of writing that, but nothing seems to work.

Here's a bigger section of the code so you can see the context

```
let urlSubfix = "\(Constant.REST_MOBILE)\(Constant.REGISTER)"
let request: APIRequest<RegisterApiResult, JSONError> = tron.request(urlSubfix)

request.method = .put

// request.headers = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]    
let header = request.headerBuilder.headers(forAuthorizationRequirement: AuthorizationRequirement.allowed, including: ["Content-Type":"application/json"])
request.headers = header

request.perform(withSuccess: { (registerApiResult) in
    print("Successfully fetched our json object")
    completion(registerApiResult)
}) { (err) in
    print("Failed to fetch json...", err)
}
```

Here is the actual error from my log:

```
Failed to fetch json... APIError<JSONError>(request: Optional(http://www.slsdist.com/eslsd5/rest/mobileservice/register), response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x618000028c20> { URL: http://www.slsdist.com/eslsd5/rest/mobileservice/register } { status code: 415, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Sat, 22 Jul 2017 22:23:14 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-Powered-By" = "Undertow/1, ASP.NET";
} }), data: Optional(0 bytes), error: Optional(Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(415))), errorModel: Optional(Go_Cart.Service.JSONError))
```

As you can see I have tried to set the headers a couple different ways, but neither of them seems to take affect.  Any help or advice from anyone would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UPDATE1: I have tried setting the AuthorizationRequirement to: none, allowed, and required, none of which worked.

Comment: UPDATE2: I have also read this SO post and it didn't help either.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477807/swift-tron-content-type-headerbuilder-syntax)

Comment: UPDATE3: Before someone down votes me for taging Alamofire, TRON is built over Alamofire and is automatially included as a dependency when you add TRON to your pod file.  I tried to tag TRON directly, but don't have the necessary 1500 (can you believe it is that high to add a tag) rep to add a new tag.

Comment: UPDATE4: So actual problem was I needed to set the encoding of my request like this:
`request.parameterEncoding = JSONEncoding.default`
Hope that helps someone else out.